# Creating multiple svn repos on single SVN Server

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I got SVN Server setup for Project A which is all good.
I now need to setup another repository in the same server for Project B.

Any guidelines please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have installed a server and setup a project in it, I believe in the following manner:

```
http://svn.exampel.com/repos/
|
|- ProjectA 
   |
   |- branches
   |- tags
   |- trunk
```

To add another repository in the same server, just go to the root directory and create another folder structure like this:

```
http://svn.exampel.com/repos/
|
|- ProjectA 
   |
   |- branches
   |- tags
   |- trunk
|
|- ProjectB
   |
   |- branches
   |- tags
   |- trunk
```

Simple!. There is no other configuration invoved and you can start using them as seperate repositories. This is called a **Multi-Repisotory Layout**.

*NOTE: The revision number will be shared with both of these, i.e., the revision number is for a complete tree and there will be a unified revision number for both the projects*

Comment: These are not separate repositories. This is just multiple projects inside one repository.

Comment: Yeah, and in SVN world, many a times, a project is called as a Repository.

Comment: I disagree. With other version control systems this might be the case, but with SVN the term repository is clearly defined and each repository has their own revision numbers. SVN documentation also talks about multiple projects inside a single repository. Mixing these will just confuse users.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a sub-folder as Arpit suggests is definitely not the solution you're looking for, since both projects would be part of a single SVN repository, hence, sharing revision numbers.

It is definitely possible to have several repositories in a single server, however there are many ways to do it depending on your setup.

First you might want to study these documents to get your concepts straight.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf

http://tortoisesvn.net/support.html

In a Windows Setup, for example, VisualSVN, through its managing tool, VisualSVN Server Manager, allows you to easily create and manage repositories in a straightforward way.

It is important that you undrstand the difference between repository as a general concept, and repository as a technical term in SVN. The cited documentation will assit you in this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, you can support multiple repositories easily with SVNParentPath configuration. See
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic for details.